# Magento Cloud Indexer and Catalog issue

Tags: magento2, cron, indexing, elasticsearch, magento2-cloud

I'm having a lot of issues during the reindex of my catalog in Magento Cloud, sometimes I saw error logs related to ElasticSearch.

How could I know if I need to request some improvement related to ElasticSearch to the Magento Cloud team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the status of your ElasticSearch running this command below in your server.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v'
```

As you can see the normal is 60% of usage, if your heap size needs to be increased, you will see high usage of it.

[image: Magento 2 ElasticSearch Heap size]

Answer (score 0):

If you can share the exact error, you can get an actual solution.

**This type of issue occurred due to different reasons.**

But mostly, It depends upon **EAV data value(attribute value)**, So you can check the value of attributes.